# Selecting from the option list in "select2" in IE8 with webdriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, jquery-select2

I have one problem simulating selecting from the option list in "select2" in IE8 using Selenium WebDriver. The problem is selecting from the dropdown elements which are not visible (needs to be scroll).
Another approach I tried is to send string to the input and to find it afterward - without no success, the string is sent to the input but the option list do not update by the entered string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this works in IE8, but try skipping the step of clicking on the select element first, just go straight to clicking on the option element you want to select.

No guarantees, but this approach works for newer browsers where there is some oddity surrounding selecting options from dropdowns, in that you don't have to (in fact it works better if you don't) replicate exact user behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to interact with invisible element:

First: Bring element into view using Selenium api and then interact with it. Following is for Ruby. There must be method in Java to achieve this.

```
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Second: Execute javascript on the element:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

Above is for Ruby. But logic will help you to achieve what you want.